# Swift alternative for android library

Tags: ios, swift, sticky

is there any swift alternate for the library (https://github.com/amarjain07/StickyScrollView) ?

i wanted to do same thing using tableview as my first cell will be collection view containing icarosel, second view will be fixed on top and then other cells of tableview will scroll inside to it.

Comment: UITableView has `plain` style. When this style is selected section's header sticks just as in library you provided. It would be wise to use iOS native feature instead of adding dependency for such thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you want to use a custom library when the `UITableView` has built-in support for it. The section header view can be made to stick like this.

Check out this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gEoiiZZE6cw) which explains the same stuff with a simple example.